# WPF sizing a ReportViewer

Tags: wpf, reportviewer

I just hope you can help me with this.
This is the case: the application that I am working for is in WPF and it has a ReportViewer inside a WindowsFormsHost like that:

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="470" Height="548"  >
        <WindowsFormsHost Margin="104,5,28,10"  Height="2000" MaxHeight="2000">
                <rv:ReportViewer x:Name="rvVentaFisica" Height="2000" />
            </WindowsFormsHost>
    </StackPanel>
```

But, I don´t get the report to show complete. The report always show a section

[image]

In fact you can see a scroll at right side, but even with this the report viewer doesn´t show the entire report.
As you can see in the properties of the ReportViewer, I've put an height value in 2000 and in the WindowsFormsHost,too. But is doesn´t work always show almost the middle of the report.

Then I decide to change the Stackpanel for a Scrollviewer, but the result was even worst, the report is shown throughout all the app, but I can see that the report can´t show the entire report even when it has a lot of free space.
[image]

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem, the height of the report was in a small size, I just change this value.